# Solving the initial value problems

Tags: analysis

Solve the initial value problems:

1. $f' = x^3f + x^7, f(0) = 2$
2. $f' = \cos(x)f - e^{\sin(x)} \sin(x), f(0) = 1$

I dont know how to solve this problems. Especially the second one because I feel like I dont understand a thing when it comes to cos and sin functions.
I appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body (as clarifications don't belong in the comments).

Comment: Is there a typo in 2? In particular, should it be $e^{\sin x}\cos x$? Or something else?

Comment: @GaryMoon I looked it up and there is no typo. Also I really appreciate  your help.

Comment: You ODEs are all of the general linear type $y'=p(x)y+q(x)$ which can be solved by integrating factor thechnique: $e^{-\int^x p(s)\,ds}(y'-p(x)y)=e^{-\int^x p(s)\,ds}q(x)$ to get $\frac{d}{dx}\Big(y(x) e^{-\int^x p(s)\,ds)}\Big) =e^{-\int^x p(s)\,ds}q(x)$. From there $$y(x)=\Big( e^{\int^x p(s)\,ds)}\Big)\int^x e^{-\int^t p(s)\,ds}q(t)\,dt +C$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us look at a general method ([integrating factor method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor)) for solving problems of the following type:
\begin{equation}
\tag{A}
 f'(x) + a_1(x) f(x) + a_0(x) = 0
\end{equation}
For example, in question (1):
$$a_1(x) = -x^3 \quad \text{and} \quad a_0(x) = -x^7$$
To solve the general equation in (A) we need to do the following:

- First, we compute the following indefinite integral
  $$ K(x) = \int a_1(x) $$
  Note that
  $$ K'(x) \equiv {d\over dx} K(x) = a_1(x) $$
- The "integrating factor" is
  $$ I(x) = e^{K(x)}$$
- We multiply both sides of (A) by $I(x)$ which gives:
  \begin{equation}
  \tag{B}
  e^{K(x)}\left(f'(x) + K'(x) f(x) + a_0(x)\right) = 0 
  \end{equation}
  We have replaced $a_1(x)$ by $K'(x)$.
- Note that equation (B) can be written as:
  \begin{equation}
  \tag{C}
  {d \over dx} \left( e^{K(x)} f(x)\right) = -e^{K(x)} a_0(x) 
  \end{equation}
- Integrating equation (C) on both sides from 0 to $z$ we get,
  \begin{equation}
  \tag{D}
   \left( e^{K(z)} f(z)\right) -  \left( e^{K(0)} f(0)\right)= -\int_{0}^z e^{K(x)} a_0(x) dx
  \end{equation}
- Renaming variables we get,
  \begin{equation}
  \tag{E}
  f(x) = \left( e^{K(0) - K(x)} f(0)\right) -e^{-K(x)}\int_{0}^x e^{K(y)} a_0(y) dy
  \end{equation}
  This is the solution of a general initial value problem of the form in (A).

Returning to the original question:

For problem (1), we need to substitute $a_1(x) = -x^3$ and $a_0(x) = -x^7$ in equation (E). First we need to compute $K(x)$.
$$
K(x) = \int a_1(x) = -{x^4 \over 4}
$$
The solution to problem in (1) is:
\begin{equation}
\tag{F}
f(x) = e^{x^4/4} f(0) + e^{x^4/4} \int_0^x e^{-y^4/4} y^7 dy
\end{equation}
The integral on the right hand side is
\begin{align}
\int_0^x e^{-y^4/4} y^7 = 4\int_0^{x^4/4} e^{-u} . u. du \quad \quad \quad (u = y^4/4) \\
{} = 4\left( 1 - e^{-x^4/4} -{x^4\over4} e^{-x^4/4}\right)
\end{align}
Equation (F) simplifies to:
$$
f(x) = 6 e^{x^4\over 4} - 4 - x^4
$$
The above expression is the solution of the first initial value problem.

Similarly to solve the second problem we need to use the following expression for $K(x)$.
$$ K(x) = -\int \cos(x) dx = -\sin(x) $$
Equation (E) eqvaluates to:
\begin{equation}
\tag{G}
f(x) = e^{\sin(x)} f(0) - e^{\sin(x)} \int_0^x e^{-\sin(y)} e^{\sin(y)} \sin(y) dy
\end{equation}

Substituting $f(0)=1$, we find that the solution to problem (2) is:
$$
f(x) = e^{\sin(x)} \cos(x)
$$

(Aside: Sometimes you will see nonlinear differential equations of the following form (special case of [Bernoulli differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation)):
$$
g'(x) - b_1(x)g(x) - b_0(x) g(x)^2 = 0 
$$
To solve such equations you first substitute $g(x) = 1/f(x)$. This substitution simplifies the above equation to:
$$
f'(x) + b_1(x) f(x) + b_0(x) = 0
$$
We know how to solve the above equation using the integrating factor method. Please check the first wikipedia link for similar nonlinear equations.
)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The steps are really helping!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an integrating factor for the first one. We rewrite the ODE as
$$y^\prime - x^3y = x^7, \ y(0)=2.$$
So, our integrating factor will be $\mu = e^{-\frac{x^4}{4}}$. Then, we multiply both sides of the ODE by $\mu$ and see that:
$$\mu y^\prime + \mu^\prime y = x^7\mu \implies (\mu y)^\prime = x^7\mu.$$
This implies that
$$\mu y = \int x^7e^{-\frac{x^4}{4}} \ dx + C.$$
If we compute the primitive, we get
$$\mu y = -e^{-\frac{x^4}{4}}(x^4+4) + C.$$
Then, we just multiply each side by $\mu^{-1}$ and then apply the IC:
$$y = 6e^\frac{x^4}{4} - x^4 - 4.$$

For the second, we use the same approach. We have
$$y^\prime - \cos x y = -e^{\sin x}\sin x, \ y(0)=1.$$
Our integrating factor will be $\mu = e^{-\sin x}$.
Multiplying each side by $\mu$ gives
$$(\mu y)^\prime = -\sin x.$$
Therefore,
$$\mu y = \cos x + C \implies y = e^{\sin x}\cos x + Ce^{\sin x}.$$
The IC $y(0)=1$ implies that $C=0$ and we have
$$y=e^{\sin x}\cos x.$$

Edit: To address the comment, $\mu$ is called an integrating factor. The purpose is to take an equation of the form $y^\prime + Py = Q$ and turn it into one of the form $(\mu y)^\prime = \mu Q$. To do this, one takes
$$\mu = \exp\bigg\{ \int P \ dx \bigg\}.$$
It's fairly straightforward to check that such a $\mu$ will do the job. Once the equation has been put into the form $(\mu y)^\prime = \mu Q$, the ODE can be solved by just integrating (hence the name).

Comment: That looks great. Thanks a lot. Is  just a variable that we chose for solving the problem?